# Hover opacity issue in Chrome

Tags: html, css, hover, opacity

Site in progress:
http://www.lazydayzzz.com/

Hi guys, I'm having some issues with a hover transition here that only seems to happen in chrome. 
When the user hovers over a tile, the background colour of the div changes and the opacity of the image goes down, as well as an icon appearing over the image.
 
In chrome it seems to reposition the image in the tile for the length of the transition.
In firefox, it works fine, and I had it working in chrome up until I started styling the footer somehow.
The problem also only seems to be with the smaller tiles, as with the big ones the transitions work fine.
Does anyone have any ideas of a possible fix?
Although the page source is available here, I can add snippets if necessary.
The site is being done for an assignment in collaboration with some journalism students.

This is the code for the tile image the image transparency go down.

```
    .griditemsmall a:hover img {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    -o-transition: 0.5;
    -moz-opacity: 0.5; 
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-opacity: 0.5;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

```
  .griditemtall a:hover img {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    -o-transition: 0.5;
    -moz-opacity: 0.5; 
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-opacity: 0.5;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 0;

}
```

This is to call the icons on hover

```
.griditemtall a:hover .entypo-mute {
    display:block;
    margin-top: -180px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please post you code ?

went i and transition it works well that shall be the problem

```
.griditemsmall {
display: inline-block;
background-color: #171818;
margin-bottom: 20px;
height: 260px;
-webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;/* Add this */
-moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

or something like

```
.gridbottomentertainment,.griditemsmall {
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;/* Add this */
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    }
```

Comment: add -webkit-transition: 0.5; that will solve your problem  now you just have for opera -o- and firefox -moz- or use the option .gridbottomentertainment,.griditemsmall i posted

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't fix the issue, the hovers work on the first column of tiles but not on the second or third as for some reason the image is being moved for the length of the transition.

Comment: i am on your website and it works on chrome for the background image

Comment: Is it working on the small images AND the tall ones?

Comment: on the tiger it s working fine add the class from the small one it will work then